# How to implement three way sliding button in Android

Tags: android, button

I want to implement a three way sliding button for my app. at the first position it should show one color, at the center it should show another color and at the end position it should change the color again. Here I am giving the images for this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I implement this?

Comment: If it's a requirement, well, what can you do... otherwise, don't create UI controls that are not standard. Users just won't lke them regardless of how useful you may think they are.

Comment: its a requirement from client...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This actually looks for my like a extend of the **seekbar**.

To implement this kind of slider I would create a class that extends **seekbar**. 
In the Constructor I would use **.setMax(2);** which means that the seekbar has only 3 positions/steps.

Then in the default implementation I would intecrate a *seekbar.OnChangeListener()*. There in the **pogressChanged(...)** method switch the background image resoure with **.setBackgroundDrawable(...)** and if necessary change the thumb with **.setThumb(...)** to a image of your desire.

If you even want to change the position of the slider you can implement a Click event handling and there change the position of the slider with **.setProgress();**

This is a very easy to handle and quick to do implementation since it requires only several lines of code.

Comment: I have to work on this but to implement the functionality this is the best approach after wasting quite some time on R&D.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using RadioGroup.

You will have to customize the RadioButtons inside RadioGroup like this:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_toggler"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="4dp">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button1_background"
        android:button="@null"
        android:checked="true" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button2_background"
        android:button="@null"
        android:checked="false" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button3_background"
        android:button="@null"
        android:checked="false" />

</RadioGroup>
```

drawable/button1_background.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn1checked"
        android:state_checked="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn1unchecked"
        android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

drawable/button2_background.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn2checked"
        android:state_checked="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn2unchecked"
        android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

drawable/button3_background.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn3checked"
        android:state_checked="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn3unchecked"
        android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

Use relevant drawable resources for all 3 buttons.
Now you can handle event on RadioGroup check change.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, I developed it for my own needs, am sharing the code. Pretty easy to do and configure. Just use a **switch** statement to find the pointer location and do something.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/md_green_100"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/send"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <SeekBar
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/md_green_100"
        android:id="@+id/transferSwitch"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:foregroundTint="@color/md_green_100"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/md_green_100"
        android:max="2"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:progress="1"
        android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/md_green_100"
        android:progressTint="@color/md_green_100"
        android:secondaryProgressTint="@color/md_green_100"
        android:thumb="@android:drawable/presence_online"
        android:thumbTint="@color/md_green_800"
        app:tickMarkTint="@color/md_green_800" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|end"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/receive"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

## Usage:

```
SeekBar seekBar = findViewById(SEEKBAR);
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
       //Do something here!
       switch(progress){
          case 0: //Left
          case 2: //Right
          case 1: default: //Center 
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
});
```

## Preview:

[image: Sweet 3-way switch]

Answer (score 0):

Create a new View and override the onPaint() method.

Draw the 'slider' bitmap in either position A, B or C (Left most, center, right most) and then set the background colour to which ever A, B, C position the view is currently in. Using Canvas.drawBitmap() - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap, float, float, android.graphics.Paint) to draw the bitmap

You can draw the background colour with - Canvas.drawRGB() **before** you draw the slider bitmap

Have some sort of event handling to change the position, for example implement onClickListener and listen for clicks. When you get a click just add 1 to the position so A -> B, B -> C, C -> A etc etc..